# Accessing Upper Shelves of 8 feet high pantry

Tags: kitchens, ladder, custom-cabinetry

I am planning a kitchen pantry which will be 8 feet high and 24 inch deep.

I need a solution to reach upper shelves of pantry - without having to pull dining chairs or put a folding step stool in bottom shelves ( making accessing items in lower shelves difficult ).

One solution might be to design a built-in step stool which folds into sides of pantry and whenever needed unfolds out.

Anybody familiar with either a product like this or custom made one ?

Comment: How much height do you need? As in, what height does the highest step need to be to make this practical?

Answer (score 1):

I mean what you are talking about is a sliding ladder - picture below.

I worked in a french bistro in the 90s that had one for storage.   This is basically the only thing that will get that high and deep along a long width.   If done right it would be "cool as sh!t".   If done wrong it would be an eye sore and in the way.   Another part of this is how big your kitchen is.   A humungous kitchen could support this.   A large kitchen that had just one wall that needed it could do it especially if there was a nook to fold it away.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to use a pull-down shelf at the top. These are normally made for handicap accessibility, but this could help remove the need for a step-stool here.

[https://www.amazon.com/DYYD-Damping-Lifting-Stainless-Suitable/dp/B0897N313G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0897N313G)

[image]

Comment: Super cool but I highly doubt a kitchen that has 8' by 2' deep shelves wants this showing.

Comment: @DMoore the op said 8’ high, how do you get shelves 8’ by 2’ ?

Answer (score 0):

My Gran had a kitchen stool with 2 steps that rotated out - made of metal and very old , never seen in shops since by me but perfect for changing bulbs as well as long, as you have good balance.

Answer (score -2):

I found two excellent solutions - one DIY and another readymade:

The common thing about both solutions is to build/buy a pull-out/push-in folding step ladder

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pepELr-hcEc&t=31s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir7D1CMXwDY

Comment: oradbanj,  it is best if you give a **detailed description of how to do what you are proposing to do** and then add links to support your answer.  Link only answers are not really helpful and will  get down votes not up votes. Please take the tour https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour  Use the edit button to make it a good answer and it will not get removed.

Comment: **Tell us how and why** to "build/buy a pull-out/push-in folding step ladder"  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer